# How to MTD, YTD in Apache Superset?

Tags: apache-superset

I would like to create a dashboard with month to date (MTD) and year to date (YTD) charts. However, I do not want to update my date range each month. A fixed date range would do this. Choosing `1 months ago` give the last 30days. Using `last month` gives me last month and everything from this month.  Yet, `this month` is not supported. `MTD` doesn't work either. I am using Superset version 0.24.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out! Use `1st` for MTD and `Jan 1st` for YTD.

For newer versions of Superset, `this quarter` is supported for quarter to date (QTD) charts.

Comment: chaisng on old comment - are you able to elaborate on the solution. Where did you use the `1st` and `Jan 1st`?

Comment: anyone using superset version 1.4? 1st now gives YTD instead of MTD.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be set on the custom tab of the time range in the chart explorer. There you can use 1st and Jan 1st as strings that are parsed.

Answer (score 0):

TO get MTD put 1st in the 'Start' field and put this month in the 'end' field

Answer (score 0):

Select Range Type as "Advanced", then enter "1st" for Start Date and leave End Date blank.    Image has today's date as End Date but leave it blank to get YTD

[TIME RANGE dialog showing YTD entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80veL.png)